# Process finished with exit code -1073741819

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rubymine

When I run a feature file in RubyMine it will randomly crash with this error. Sometimes it will run one scenario other times it will run a couple before giving this error but it always does. We thought it had something to do with the version of IE we were using but it seems to occur with all versions. Also this issue doesn't seem to affect everyone and we're unsure as to what causes it because the settings on each environment are the same... Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if they're related, but if I run it in the console Ruby interpreter crashes.... "Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.3p0 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think that this is the solution but so far it seems to have fixed my code... In my hooks file I have an after block that among other things has the line @browser.quit I've tracked the failure down to this line and when I comment this line out I don't get the error. Like I said I don't know if this is actually the cause of the problem but so far it seems to have resolved it... Just thought I'd share.

Edit: Ok I found out the *real* solution. Apparently somewhere in the command "quit" there's a bug that causes the -1073... error. Instead of using "quit" I switched it to ".close" and that seems to have resolved it. The close command will cleanly close out of the browser instance without any errors.

Comment: I've done a little more testing and it seems either the .close or .quit events of the selenium web-driver has problems when there are multiple windows open at once.

Answer (score 0):

There shoudn't be any crashes in Ruby. If that's the case then there is a bug deep down in the Ruby Interpreter of your choice where there shouldn't be one. Try to get a debug report for this and report on Ruby Redmine or the equivalent issue tracker.