# Webrick suddenly exits with "Process finished with exit code -1073741819"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Jetbrains RubyMine 6.0.3 Rails 3.2.17 and WEBrick 1.3.1 on windows 7. When running the application suddenly Webrick exists with message "Process finished with exit code -1073741819". Any idea what condition throws such error code? I am using gems watir.

Comment: Any more informative stack trace? Could you try launching your rails app via a command line and see what you get?

Comment: While I am trying to run from command line, I run rails s and then it shows standrad message like booting etc .... than I run my url in the browser and it took me back to prompt without any message.

Comment: First, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067196/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819 which is very similar. A very quick Google search of "1073741819" suggests it is an Access Violation message. Do you have an antivirus running on your system? If so, disable it and then try running the server. If it works, configure exclusions for WEBrick.

Comment: Also https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/100. A user reports that upgrading his version of Ruby to the latest build of 1.9.3 fixed his issues.

Comment: Disabling antivirus did not solve the problem. But I updated Rubymine to 6.3.3 - and now I am not finding the problem anymore, ( though not sure about the cause of the problem ). Thanks a lot for the help. Appreciate it much.

Comment: @user3437334: Updating to RubyMine 6.3.3 didn't solve the problem. My environment is the same: Windows 7 x64, WEBrick and RubyMine 6.3.3 (was 6.0.3). I chose to uninstall 6.0.3 without deteting settings.